# Convert array to particular JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am kicking my self for having to ask this question, but I cannot figure out how to convert the following array to the JSON format below. Simply `json_encoding` the array does not produce the square brackets needed.

PHP Array

```
$json = array(
              "api_key" => $api_key,
              "data"    => array(
                                "item" => array (
                                                "value" => rand(0, 5684),
                                                "text" => "Total"
                                                )
                                )
             );
```

JSON format required

```
{
    "api_key": "api key",
    "data": {
        "item": [
            {
                "value": 3212,
                "text": "Total"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How should I change the array to make json_encode produce the correct format, or is there some switch I am missing on the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing out a level. In your PHP, `item` is an associative array with the `value` and `text` properties. But in the expected JSON, it's an array **containing** an object with `value` and `text` properties. So in your PHP structure, you need a simple array that you put your associative array *in*.

E.g.:

```
$json = array(
  "api_key" => $api_key,
  "data" => array(
    "item" => array( // <== The simple array
      array(         // <== Your original associative array
        "value" => rand(0, 5684) ,
        "text" => "Total"
      )
    )
  )
);
```

If you `json_encode` that, you get:

```
{
    "api_key": "your key",
    "data": {
        "item": [
            {
                "value": 605,
                "text": "Total"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly I'm done for the day :-/ Thanks for not ripping me a new one for being so dense.

Comment: @superphonic: It's pretty easy not to see the odd `[` and `]` here and there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `item` to be a list of dictionaries, you need an array of associative arrays in the input:

```
$json = array(
   "api_key" => 'foo',
   "data"    => array(
      "item" => array(
         array (
            "value" => rand(0, 5684),
            "text" => "Total"
         )
      )
   )
);
```